# Going back to outline slide after each main slide in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I would like to have outline slides in the presentation, that are identical, and changes made in one slides are tracked in another.

The idea is to have an outline slide, then some "meat" slides, followed by the copy of the outline slide. I would like to work on the presentation, but also want these two outline slides to be identical at all times.

Something like:

```
A -> Outline -> B -> Outline -> C -> outline -> ...
```

Is there a way to achieve that in MS PowerPoint? [Here is an example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h5q5w9qy6qfwbc6/ExampleForSuperUserStackExchange.pptx?dl=0) sketch of what I am trying to do.

I don't want to manually type slide # every time I want to jump to outline, nor use hyperlinks (if possible). I couldn't find any other ways to do it.

PS: I have Win and Mac versions of MS Office 365

Comment: If you are making a presentation to display then just have one copy of the slide that you want to be the same and set up the slide show to display that one slide whenever you need to see it. If this sounds like what you need to do, I'll make it an answer with some screen shots.

Comment: @MoragHughson i think what you describe is exactly what i am looking for.

Comment: OK - done. Let me know if the description is not clear or you need further help with this.

Answer (score 3):

When an identical slide is needed several times in a presentation (for example an agenda slide), rather than trying to keep several copies of that slide in sync, instead create a slide show which shows (the one single copy of) the slide whenever it is needed.

To do this select "Custom Slide Show" from the "Slide Show" menu (screenshots from PowerPoint 2010, but this feature is not new), and in the little pop-up choose "New...". Give your custom show a name, and then select and "Add>>" each slide from the left to the right, selecting the "Outline" side (as it is named in this example) whenever it is needed. Use the up and down arrows on the far right to rearrange the slide show list.

[image: Powerpoint 2010: Define Custom Show dialog]

**Note:** this isn't the greatest example of a UI from Microsoft, the window cannot be resized; you can select and add multiple slides from the left window to the right, but when you add them, they always go to the end which can be very frustrating if you have a long presentation and then need to add a slide to somewhere near the beginning having already made the slide show! For short presentations, it's less likely to frustrate.

Please bear in mind that if you add more slides, you need to update the slide show. Always run your presentation in screenshow mode before you actually present it to make sure you haven't forgotten to add any slides.

Finally, suggest you also go to "Set Up Slide Show" (also on the "Slide Show" menu), and set it up so that your newly created slide show is what is shown by default. Then save the presentation so it remembers that setting too.

[image: Powerpoint 2010: Set Up Show dialog]

If you don't do this, you have to select the custom show when you need to present, and that's easy to forget. You do it by clicking on the arrow below "Custom Slide Show" (the option you used earlier) where you will see your newly created custom show will now be listed. However, if you set it up as the default as shown above, you don't need to remember to do this.

[image: Powerpoint 2010: Custom Slide Show menu shows list of custom shows in this file]

Comment: i will try it out and come back to comment. thank you! upvoted for details and screens

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Morag's suggestion:

Create a custom show for each of your "meat" sections.
Create the outline/agenda slide, and for each point, create a hyperlink to the appropriate custom show, choosing the show and return option.

Advantages: you won't need to update as extensively when you add more slides; just add the new slide(s) to the appropriate custom show.

Possible disadvantage: Morag's suggestion will work beautifully whether the show is delivered by a speaker or unattended/by someone who's not familiar with the links. My suggestion assumes that someone's there to click the links in order to invoke each section of "meat" slides.